# Passing C# bool to java dll - invalid arguments

Tags: java, c#, dll, interop

Working with legacy code [Pogamut C# integration](http://pogamut.cuni.cz/main/tiki-view_blog_post.php?postId=20) providing a link between C# and java. When calling a constructor, setting certain parameters requiring a `boolean` input, I get

> "the overloaded method has some invalid arguments"

error from intellisense (VS2012).

The java original looks like this:

```
getAct().act(new Configuration().setDrawTraceLines(true).setAutoTrace(true));
```

My C# translation looks like this:

```
        Configuration cmd = new Configuration();
        cmd.setDrawTraceLines(true);
        cmd.setAutoTrace(true);
        bot.getAct().act(cmd);
```

I've split it up to show where the error occurs. I get a.m. error on the `setDrawTracelines(true)` and `setAUtoTrace(true)`.

Part of the `PogamutCs.dll` interface is show below, which to me suggests that the calls are correct:

```
namespace cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbcommands
{
    public class Configuration : CommandMessage
    {
        public Configuration();
        public Configuration(Configuration p0);
        public Configuration(DummyConstructorSelector selector);
        public Configuration(UnrealId p0, Boolean p1, Boolean p2, string p3, string p4, Double p5, Rotation p6, Boolean p7, Double p8, Boolean p9, Boolean p10, Boolean p11, Boolean p12, Boolean p13);

        public virtual Configuration setAction(string p0);
        public virtual Configuration setAutoPickupOff(Boolean p0);
        public virtual Configuration setAutoTrace(Boolean p0);
        public virtual Configuration setDrawTraceLines(Boolean p0);
```

My guess it is something with the `bool / boolean`. To try this, I have added the following assignment, that requires a string rather than a boolean:

```
  cmd.setAction("bla");
```

Intellisense has no problems with this call.

If indeed the `bool / boolean` is the the issue, then how do I create a `boolean` type `true` in C# to pass to the `.dll`?

Comment: If C# is similar to Java, then try to change Boolean to boolean in your PogamutCs.dll

Comment: What you have shown complies fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TQZUK2

Comment: @JFPicard: after some searching, I think the java Boolean is an object type (i.e. boxed primitive), whereas C# bool is a primitive. Is there a way to fix this on the C# side rather than on the java dll side? I think I have a similar issue where the .dll returns a Boolean which I then need to evaluate in C# in if(Boolean). This also fails with "cannot implicitly convert type". I assume C# expects a bool.

Comment: Maybe you can do something like .toString() to get a string representation of the boolean like in Java ?